# How to find correct image by using jquery index

Tags: jquery, css, indexing

I would need to find a certain image in a div and show it. But the the thing is that I click on a different image. Here's the code:

```
<div id="images">
<img src="but1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="but2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="but3.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="but4.jpg" class="zoomImage" alt="" />
<img src="but5.jpg" class="zoomImage" alt="" />
<img src="but6.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="images2" style="display:none;">
<img src="butB4.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="butB5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Now if I click some of the images that has the class `zoomImage`, I would like to show (give `display:block;`) to image that is in `images2` div. For example if I would click on

```
 <img src="but4.jpg" class="zoomImage" alt="" />
```

it should show up

```
<img src="butB4.jpg" alt="" />
```

and if I would click on

```
<img src="but5.jpg" class="zoomImage" alt="" />
```

it should show up

```
<img src="butB5.jpg" class="zoomImage" alt="" />
```

and then if I would click on

```
<img src="but6.jpg" alt="" />
```

nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#images img.zoomImage').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data("index", i).click(function(){
         $('#images2').show().find("img").hide().eq($(this).data("index")).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @marcovic - Please check I have edited my answer based on my understanding of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, that matches the images in `#images` with the class `zoomImage` and tries to find an image with the same number in `#images2` and `.show()` it.

```
$('#images img.zoomImage').click(function() {
    var imageNo = $(this).attr('src').replace(/^.*(\d+)\.jpg$/, '$1');
    $('#images2 img[src="butB' + imageNo + '.jpg"').show();
});
```

If, as suggested by you in comments, the image numbers are not consistent.  But the images appear in the `#images2` DIV in the same order as images with the `.zoomImage` class appear in the `#images` DIV above, then you could use the following code.

```
$('#images img.zoomImage').click(function() {
    var imageNo = $('#images img.zoomImage').index(this);
    $('#images2 img:eq(' + imageNo + ')').show();
});
```

If you wish to be able to close the images with a subsequent click, use `.toggle()` instead of `.show()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did copy all the markup there. Some of the images don't have numbers in their names.

What I was thinking, could I somehow how get index number of those images that have class zoomImage? And then with that index number hook it in second div?

Comment: @marcovic: So you mean, if you have two images that have `.zoomImage` class, then you will expect there to be two images in the `#images2` DIV?  That is fine.  I'll make a secondary version.

Comment: Yes, and they are always in same order (first image in images div has the bigger version first in the images2 div).

Answer (score 0):

Made the response so that it corresponds to your latest comments:

HTML:

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="but1.jpg" alt="1" />
    <img src="but2.jpg" alt="2" />
    <img src="but3.jpg" alt="3" />
    <img src="but4.jpg" class="zoomImage" alt="4" />
    <img src="but5.jpg" class="zoomImage" alt="5" />
    <img src="but6.jpg" alt="6" />
</div>

<div id="images2">
    <img src="butB4.jpg" alt="B4" />
    <img src="butB5.jpg" alt="B5" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#images2 > img {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#images > img.zoomImage').each(function(index) {
        var imageNumber = (index + 1);
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#images2 > img:nth-child(' + imageNumber + ')').show();
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F99Zn/)